# Binary path in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, docker

I am running pgadmin via Docker desktop. I am unable to restore a sql file in the database. I get the following message - "Please configure the PostgreSQL Binary Path in the Preferences dialog."

In the case of PostgreSQL installed in the device, I am aware about assigning the binary path. However in this case, pgadmin is accessed via docker.

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Works for me with not special steps.  You need to give us enough info to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, an installation of pgAdmin includes the PostgreSQL client. pgAdmin cannot operate without the client shared library `libpq.so` installed, and it also makes use of `pg_dump`, `pg_restore` and `psql`. If you don't have these three executables, the functionality of pgAdmin will be reduced.

I don't know how the SQL file you want to restore was generated, but if it is a text-format dump generated with `pg_dump` that contains `COPY` statements, you need `psql` to restore it.